# Using mxgraph with AngularJs. Error ReferenceError: mxGraph is not defined. How to resolve this?

Tags: angularjs, mxgraph

I am trying to use angular js with mxgraph.

Here is my code

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];

        $scope.main = function(container)
        {
            alert("hai");
                // Creates the graph inside the given container
                var graph = new mxGraph(container);

                // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
                // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
                var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

                // Adds cells to the model in a single step
                graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
                try
                {
                    var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello,', 20, 20, 80, 30);
                    var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'World!', 200, 150, 80, 30);
                    var e1 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', v1, v2);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Updates the display
                    graph.getModel().endUpdate();
                }
            //}
        };

});
```

But I am getting `mxGraph is not defined` error. How Can I solve this? or can any one tell me how to use mxgraph with angularjs in a right way.

Comment: did you try injecting it as `dependency` in your `module`

Comment: How can i do that I am using angular js 1

Comment: something like `var app = angular.module("myApp", ['mxGraph']);` might help

Comment: then in controller I have to pass the mxGraph  like this app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,mxGraph). I tried  but its shows s Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Answer (score 0):

mxGraph is a great library for making shapes, vertex and edges, and it can be turned into a module by doing the following:

```
 var mxGraph = angular.module('mxGraph', []);
mxGraph.factory('mxgraph', function() {
       return window.mxGraph; 
});

var app = angular.module('app', ['mxGraph']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'mxgraph', function($scope, mxgraph) {
         $scope.main = function(container)
    {

            // Creates the graph inside the given container
            var graph = new mxgraph(container);

            // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
            // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
            var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

            // Adds cells to the model in a single step
            graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
            try
            {
                var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello,', 20, 20, 80, 30);
                var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'World!', 200, 150, 80, 30);
                var e1 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', v1, v2);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Updates the display
                graph.getModel().endUpdate();
            }
        //}
    };
}]);
```

This allows the application to continue in the AngularJS dependency injection fashion which would allow mxGraph work seamless.